# Integration ActiveMQ5.6.0 web-console in GlassFish 3.0.1

Tags: java, glassfish, integration, activemq-classic, glassfish-embedded

Hello guys have such issue i do all like this tutorial says
[javadudeTutorial](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/glassfish-v3-1-running-embedded-activemq-for-jms-part-1/)

But i can not to deploy web-console.war in GlassFish. and the stack trace says me only

There is no installed container capable of handling this application com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared.FileArchive@1b9b6ab5

What i do wrong. all other steps i have benn passed.

Comment: There is no installed container capable of handling this application com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared.FileArchive@1b9b6ab5

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to delete all OSGi headers in manifest.mf in web-console.war. But i really do not understand why i should to edit war file and how to fix it using GlassFish properties... Any suggestions?